# How to achieve interrupt in Linux serial port?

Tags: c++, linux, serial-port

I know SO isn't the right place for theoretical questions, but rather for code exchange.
Nevertheless, i can't find a complete solution so once again i'm putting my faith in SO community.

***Problem:***

As i worked with STM32 before i'm trying to replicate the UART interface. It's working well, but the questions arose.

> It is possible to allow the ttyS# port to just ignore read() if the buffer file is empty?

> Do i have to set it up by termios params or use Linux libs?

I had this problem, with STM32 ports, but it was solved via the interrupt interface in HAL libs. When it comes to Linux, i`m not sure.

I use:

```
fd = open("/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0);
fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK /* | O_ASYNC*/); //> doesn't suit well cause app reads its own data
```

Comment: Are you just asking how to do a nonblocking read?

Comment: have your tried what is described in this Post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15119412/setting-serial-port-interruption-in-linux Regards
Jan

Comment: @airjabus, yes and it works almost perfect, but at random runs, the Linux port reads only its own msg-s. Therefore, i decided to ask more basic questions, thinking Barath Ravikumar and others were on the wrong path.

Comment: Your Linux program is not accessing a UART "*port*", but rather a serial terminal in a multitasking OS. Unless your program is properly constructed, nonblocking I/O is typically inefficient, adds read latency, and is to the detriment of all other processes.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25996171/linux-blocking-vs-non-blocking-serial-read/26006680#26006680

Comment: @sawdust, apologies for the inappropriate terminology. I know about inefficiency, but my goal is to make the UART interface capable of sudden external devices disconnection. Therefore, the stalling on read() is unacceptable (for simplicity i use only TX/RX/GND). I'm reading about C++ ports management, but there is a lot to learn). Thanks for the link.